# flag which text file has the key word

Tags: r

I am trying to flag which text file has the key word "THE BEST LOGLIKELIHOOD VALUE HAS BEEN REPLICATED." in my 100 text files.
I have a file which has 100 text files, and I want to know which text file contains the key sentence" THE BEST LOGLIKELIHOOD VALUE HAS BEEN REPLICATED.".

How could I use R to flag which text file has the key sentence?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

May be this will be get you started. If all the text files are in the working directory

```
Pat <-  "THE BEST LOGLIKELIHOOD VALUE HAS BEEN REPLICATED."
indx <- sapply(
  filelist,
  function(x) 
  {
    any(grepl(Pat, readLines(x), fixed = TRUE))
  }
)
```

#### Update

Using three example files I created

```
indx
file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt 
# TRUE     FALSE      TRUE 

filelistNew <- filelist[indx]
lapply(filelistNew, 
       function(x)  write.csv(readLines(x),file=gsub("txt","csv",x),
              row.names=F))###In case you wanted to write the files to another folder, 
         #use `paste` i.e. `....file=paste(path, gsub("txt","csv",x), sep="/"),...`

list.files(pattern="file")
[1] "file1.csv" "file1.txt" "file2.txt" "file3.csv" "file3.txt"
```

You can open the `.csv` file in excel.  You may also check `library(XLConnect)` or `library(xlsx)`

Comment: `filelist=list.files(path="C:\\Users\\Mia\\Desktop\\data 35\\3 class\\correct",pattern=".out")`'Pat <-  "THE BEST LOGLIKELIHOOD VALUE HAS BEEN REPLICATED."'sapply(filelist,function(x) grepl(Pat, readLines(x)))' it showed me that  Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, "r") : cannot open file 'c1.out': No such file or directory

Comment: @Richie Cotton here is my all text file in the working directory `filelist=list.files(path="C:\\Users\\Mia\\Desktop\\data 35\\3 class\\correct",pattern=".out")` and I added your code, but it gave me Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, "r") : cannot open file 'Bluetooth': Permission denied

Comment: thanks! I tried. It works. But how could I save the results as the xlsx file, becasue "slappy{...}" is logical , so how could I save it?

Comment: @zaq0718.  It is not clear about the contents of the file.  I updated the code.

Comment: @zaq0718 Pass `full.names = TRUE` to `list.files`.